# unable to update notion Title field with a number field in pages.update

Tags: notion-api, notion, notion-js

When trying to update a notion page ala

```
notionClient.pages.update({
  page_id: updatePageId,
  properties: updateObj
});
```

why does this work

```
updateBlockObj = {
  "Title":{"title":[{"text":{"content":"I AM TdITLE"}}]}
};
```

and this also works:

```
updateBlockObj = {
  "numberfield":101,
};
```

but this does not

```
updateBlockObj = {
  "numberfield":101,
  "Title":{"title":[{"text":{"content":"I AM TdITLE"}}]}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        const updateBlockObj = {
          "Tags": {
            "multi_select": [
              {"name":"rrr"},
              {"name":'ttt'}
            ]
          },
          "numberfield": {
            number: 200
          },
          "Title": {
            "title":[{
              "text": {
                "content": "I AM TdITxcxxLE"
              }
            }]
          }
        };
```